# s3 UNLOAD is successful but loads no data

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am running below Unload command to load data from redshift into s3. Command is run successfully but I do not see any file in redshift, verified that the s3 path exists and credentials are correct.

I do not have any message to debug it further. Any pointers will be helpful.

```
    UNLOAD ('select  col1, col2, col3 
 from <table_name>')
  TO 's3://<path>' CREDENTIALS
    'aws_access_key_id=<key>;aws_secret_access_key=<pwd>'
  MANIFEST
  GZIP
  ALLOWOVERWRITE
  ESCAPE
  NULL AS '\\N';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not see any file in redshift"? The `UNLOAD` command takes data _out of Amazon Redshift_ and puts it _into Amazon S3_. Do you mean that no file was created in the S3 bucket under that path? (By the way, the path doesn't have to pre-exist because S3 does not support directories. Instead, the filename will include the full path.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have appropriate read/write permission to the bucket where your are writing the data. 
Link below provides more examples to solve your problem

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html

Regards,
Rama

Comment: Cool...this works afer I change the write permissions on the s3 bucket. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are pointers to go through one by one--

1. See if your query really works and return records by running it in terminal or psql, `select  col1, col2, col3  from <table_name>`
2. If you specify `s3://<path>` then, the actual file gets created in S3 will `s3://<path>000` if you make parallel OFF. Similarly, if you do parallel on, multiple files will be created with similar name pattern.

In your case you are using MENIFEST, hence unload `MENIFEST` file name will be `s3://<path>manifest`.

3. Other simple thing, you could do is, do a list on S3 path and then check files manually.
   `s3cmd ls s3://path/`

Comment: Thanks, the issue with write privileges on the bucket!